# Can I use 16V power adapter for scanners that need 12V?

Tags: power, adapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Will they be damaged? The two HP deskjet 2400 and 4300C scanners need 12V, 1.25A as I read. I only have a 16V, 3.36A power adapter with the connector they require.
Will I break them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must use a 12V adapter rated for >= 1.25A.